# Solr - indexing large database

Tags: java, mysql, apache, jdbc, solr

I'd like to index database (MySQL) in Solr. Database has one table, but it has 50 columns and almost 4 milions rows. It's around 1.5GB.

I configured `solrconfig.xlm`, `solr-data-config.xml`, and in `schema.xml` I've added:

```
<dynamicField name="*"  type="text_general"   multiValued="false" indexed="true"  stored="true" />
```

Because every fields are text.

When I try to import data it take a few seconds and nothing happens. I got

> Requests: 1, Fetched: 0, Skipped: 0, Processed: 0

There is a error in logs:

> java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected exception encountered during query.
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2866)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollbackNoChecks(ConnectionImpl.java:5191)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:5074)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4667)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:1640)    at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.closeConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:484)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.close(JdbcDataSource.java:469)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.closeEntityProcessorWrappers(DocBuilder.java:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:480)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:461)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer.readFieldLength(Buffer.java:289)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer.fastSkipLenString(Buffer.java:170)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.unpackField(MysqlIO.java:708)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:428)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3222)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2393)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2816)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2820)   ...
>   11 more

I've tried with small database and it worked, every fields have indexed. I have problem only with large base.

I changed `ramBufferSizeMB` and `maxBufferedDocs` in `solrconfig.xlm` to 2GB and 4GB, but it doesn't help. I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't just use MySQL indexes.  What problem is solved by having the data both in MySQL and indexed by Solr?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's not my invention. It's a task to introduce MySQL and Solr.

Comment: Solr has vastly greater support for handling proper searching than what MySQL supports. For the problem, try with a different batchSize setting. From the FAQ: DataImportHandler is designed to stream row one-by-one. It passes a fetch size value (default: 500) to Statement#setFetchSize which some drivers do not honor. For MySQL, add batchSize property to dataSource configuration with value -1. This will pass Integer.MIN_VALUE to the driver as the fetch size and keep it from going out of memory for large tables.

Comment: @MatsLindh I've "solved" problem by importing date in several parts, but now I've checked your solution and it works excellent!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with a different batchSize setting.

[From the FAQ](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq#I.27m_using_DataImportHandler_with_a_MySQL_database._My_table_is_huge_and_DataImportHandler_is_going_out_of_memory._Why_does_DataImportHandler_bring_everything_to_memory.3F):

> DataImportHandler is designed to stream row one-by-one. It passes a fetch size value (default: 500) to Statement#setFetchSize which some drivers do not honor. For MySQL, add batchSize property to dataSource configuration with value -1. This will pass Integer.MIN_VALUE to the driver as the fetch size and keep it from going out of memory for large tables.